C++のstd::functionクラスに、std::reference_wrapperを引数に取る代入演算子が定義されているのは、なぜですか？
functionクラスには、以下の二つの代入演算子があります。
template <typename F>
function& operator=(F&& f)
{
   function(std::forward<F>(f)).swap(*this);
   return *this;
}

template <typename F>
function& operator=(reference_wrapper<F> f)
{
   function(f).swap(*this);
   return *this;
}

functionのコンストラクタは以下のように定義されていて、ユニバーサル参照で受け取るようになっています。
template <typename F>
function(F&& f);

代入演算子を2種類定義することで、コンストラクタは必ずreference_wrapperの左辺値参照で受け取るようになっています。しかし、コンストラクタにはreference_wrapper用のものがないので、reference_wrapperの右辺値を渡すことはできますし、そもそも右辺値を渡さないようにしている理由がわからないです。
なぜreference_wrapperを引数に取る代入演算子を定義しているのでしょうか？

（私はド素人なのですが）https://cpprefjp.github.io/reference/functional/function/op_assign.html を見てみると，引数が reference_wrapper な側は noexcept となっているようです．この辺が関係あったりしませんか？

@fana 確かにそれが関係していそうです。
libstdc++の実装では、汎用の方に
noexcept(_Handler<_Functor>::template _S_nothrow_init<_Functor>())
と書かれていたので、コピーコンストラクタがnoexcept指定されているreference_wrapperでは、まったく同じだと勘違いしていました。

以下の関数の実装を考えます
template <typename F>
function& operator=(reference_wrapper<F> f)
{
   function(f).swap(*this);
   return *this;
}

functionのコンストラクタには以下の宣言があります
template <class F>
function(F f);  

左辺値型はこちらに渡すものと考えられます
以下はreference_wrapperの使用例です
template <class T>
void g(T x)
{
  f(x);
}

int main()
{
  int x = 3;

  // 関数テンプレートの型推論によって、xの型が非参照のintと見なされる
//g(x);

  // 関数テンプレートに変数を参照として渡す
  g(std::ref(x));

  std::cout << x << std::endl;
}

ここで用いられるstd::refはreference_wrapperを返します
template <class T>
  reference_wrapper<T> ref(T& t) noexcept;

そしてfunctionのオペレーター関数にはreference_wrapperの仮引数があります
template <typename F>
function& operator=(reference_wrapper<F> f)

以下の節に注目します
int x = 3;
g(std::ref(x));

reference_wrapperを受け取った関数gはint xの参照を受け取ります
ここで再度以下の実装を確認します
template <typename F>
function& operator=(reference_wrapper<F> f)
{
   function(f).swap(*this);
   return *this;
}

仮引数fはreference_wrapperなのでFの参照を有しています
先述のget(std::ref(x))の例からここではfunction(f)がfunction(std::ref(F))に等しいと言えます
再度以下のコンストラクタを考えます
template <class F>
function(F f);

これは以下の定義に相当すると考えられます
template <class T>
void g(T x)
{
  f(x);
}

よってFの値渡しに対応するコンストラクタがそのままreference_wrapperを介した参照を受け取る関数として挙動することになり、実質的な左辺値型用のオーバーロードになると推察できます
コメントへの補足

・operator=(reference_wrapper)を呼び出すときには必ず値渡しされる

functionのコンストラクタ実装はこちらですね
確かにtemplate<class F> function(F&& f);となっています
日本語版は誤植のようです
一方でfunctionの使用例は以下となります
int inc(int n) { return n + 1; }
 
int main()
{
    std::function<int(int)> f1;
    std::function<int(int)> f2(inc);
    assert(f1 == nullptr and f2 != nullptr);
 
    f1 = f2; // overload (1)
    assert(f1 != nullptr and f1(1) == 2);
 
    f1 = std::move(f2); // overload (2)
    assert(f1 != nullptr and f1(1) == 2);
    // f2 is in valid but unspecified state
 
    f1 = nullptr; // overload (3)
    assert(f1 == nullptr);
 
    f1 = inc; // overload (4)
    assert(f1 != nullptr and f1(1) == 2);
 
    f1 = [](int n) { return n + n; }; // overload (4)
    assert(f1 != nullptr and f1(2) == 4);
 
    std::reference_wrapper<int(int)> ref1 = std::ref(inc);
    f1 = ref1; // overload (5)
    assert(f1 != nullptr and f1(1) == 2);
}

サンプルコードの通り、このクラスのインスタンスは関数を受け取ることが前提です
変数(関数名)は、左辺値型、右辺値型、そしてポインタ(右辺値)型を戻り値として定義します
void test(void (&&test)(int)){
    printf("%lld\n",(unsigned long long int)&test);
};

void sample(int){};

int main(void){
    using namespace std;
    
    printf("%lld\n",(unsigned long long int)&sample);
    reference_wrapper<void(int)> func=ref(sample);
    test(func);
};

94690101248471
94690101248471

この例の通り、同一のアドレスを指します
つまり、functionのオペレータ関数で関数領域を受け取っている限り、変数は逐次その戻り値を変換します
よって変数が左辺値型であっても、コンストラクタの仮引数が右辺値型であれば、それが実引数として渡る仕組みです
すなわち引数が右辺値型だったとしても右辺値参照として扱われます

functionクラスのコンストラクタのシグネチャなのですが、以下のようになっていると思います。(C++日本語リファレンスに書かれている内容は誤り)
template<class F> function(F&& f);
なので、違いが生まれるのは以下の部分だと思います。
・operator=(reference_wrapper)を呼び出すときには必ず値渡しされる
・operator=(reference_wrapper)内のコンストラクタ呼出は、必ずreference_wrapperの左辺値参照を渡す
仮にC++日本語リファレンスに書かれている内容が正しくても、汎用のoperator=内のstd::forwardが無意味となって、ほぼ同じ処理になるのではないかと思います。

すみません。
template<class F> function(F f);からtemplate<class F> function(F&& f);に、C++23から変更があったようです。なので、誤りではなかったです。
std::functionの提案段階では、template<typename F> function& operator= (F);というように定義されていたようなので、そこが関係していると思われます。

最初の提案時点では、以下のように定義されていました。
template <typename F> function(F, const Allocator& = Allocator());
template <typename F> function(reference_wrapper<F>, const Allocator& = Allocator());
template <typename F> function& operator=(F);
template <typename F> function& operator=(reference_wrapper<F>);

その後、reference_wrapperは転送関数オブジェクトであるので、reference_wrapperをとるコンストラクタが不要になりました。
そして、以下の実装では2回値渡しが発生して無駄があるということで、ユニバーサル参照で受け取るように変更されました。
template <typename F> function& operator=(F f) {
    function(f).swap(*this);
    return *this;
}

そして、C++11の規格と同じになったのだと思われます。(C++23では、コンストラクタもユニバーサル参照で受け取るようになった。)
最初の提案時点では、2つのoperator=は例外を投げるか投げないかの違いしかなかったため、

noexcept指定のために2種類定義した
コンストラクタと対称的にするために定義したが、function(reference_wrapper)を削除した後に、operator=(reference_wrapper)を削除し忘れた

のどちらかが理由なのではないかと思います。(削除し忘れるということがあるのかわからないですが)
